# Query table using relid instead of the table name

Tags: sql, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm using node-postgres to return a joined table to the front end of my React app through an express server. Here is the query...

```
SELECT channels.name as channels, programmes.title as title, series.number as series, episodes.episode_number as episode
         ​FROM programmes
         ​INNER JOIN programme_channels ON programme_channels.programme_id = programmes.programme_id
         ​INNER JOIN channels ON programme_channels.channel_id = channels.channel_id
         ​INNER JOIN series ON programmes.programme_id = series.programme_id
         ​INNER JOIN episodes ON series.series_id = episodes.series_id
```

This works as needed, however I'd like for front-end users to be able to update or delete columns of the table. To do this, each cell of my table would need to know the origin of its data. Currently the query I have returns a table like this...

```
 channel      | title      | series        | episode 
--------------+------------+---------------+---------
 Some Channel | Some title |             1 |       1
```

Where channel is from the channels, title, series and episode are all from different tables. For a user to update or delete this data, they will need the origins of each column for the query.

The node-postgres query returns some more information which may be helpful for this in the form of a fields array...

```
fields: [
Field {
  name: 'title',
  tableID: 16554,
  columnID: 2,
  dataTypeID: 1043,
  dataTypeSize: -1,
  dataTypeModifier: 104,
  format: 'text'
},
...]
```

and I can return a table with the original table name of a column using this query...

```
SELECT relname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables
WHERE relid = '16554'
```

result...

```
 relname  
----------
 programmes
```

however I'm not sure how to use the results of this to query the table 'programmes'. This is where I've hit a wall. My questions are...

1. Am I going about this the right way, or is there an easier way to update data returned from a joined table?
2. If so, is there any way I can SELECT a table by either the `relid` or the result of a query.

Comment: I think the conventional solution is to have your React application understand the source of all of the data semantically. So if a user click a field and edits it and presses save, then React knows what column updated, and it issues the correct api calls to the backend (express) to update the data. Conventionally using RESTful apis these days.